# SPI not working properly with high micocontroller speed

Tags: microcontroller, spi

I am interfacing some SPI based sensors with a MSP430 micro controller.
The problem is :

The micro controller is operating at 20Mhz and the SPI clock is 1 Mhz.

When i am reducing the speed of micro to around <4 Mhz then the interface is working fine, But when i increase it , i get junk data from SPI slave.

What precautions do i need to take to handle these kind of problems.,

Comment: I'm running a 4MHz SPI link between a 72MHz master and a 100MHz slave CPU - the CPU frequency has nothing to say here. I would recommend you use interrupts to handle the SPI periphereal and maybe consider using DMA as well.

Answer (score 0):

On an MSP430, one usually uses the USCI peripheral in SPI mode to run the interface. That peripheral allows selecting the source of the clock generated as the SPI master as well as controlling the divide down of the clock to match the clock rate accepted by the SPI slave. Check out the UCSSELx bits in the UCAxCTL1 register. Depending upon the clock source selected, you may then need to prescale the generated clock using the USCI_Ax bit rate control registers. It sounds from your question that you are running the SPI on SMCLK with no prescaling. That would explain why reducing the CPU frequency makes the SPI peripheral work. You will be better off from a system point of view keeping SMCLK at a high frequency and then prescaling the SPI master clock to match the limits of the attached peripheral.

Deciding how the clocks are to be used is often a system issue. You will need to consider the source of the clocks, i.e. ACLK or SMCLK, and the limits of the attached peripherals. This should tell you how you may need to prescale the higher speed clocks (i.e. SMCLK) to match the limitations of the SPI slave. It is usually complicated enough that I have to draw it out to make sure I can meet all the peripheral requirements.